# Making the Cursor Disappear

Tags: php, jquery, css, cursor

I am constructing an Editor for a little Webapp. My concept is to have a Bar where I put all the functions. It changes concerning to the content. Now i got the following problem. As you can see in the [picture](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/FPOOEeEok77eqBod0yOS0A?authkey=DKo-MXLLwDk&feat=directlink) when i click on the button it happens that the button will be on a new button just after beeing clicked. My question is: Is there a possibility to make the cursor disappear? We are coding in PHP.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean the mouse cursor disappear?
If so, you can use css to use any gif as your mouse cursor, even a transparent one.

Because of the image, I think you speak German?
If you answered all questions with yes up to here, then look [here](http://www.css4you.de/cursor.html).

---

Edit: I think I did what you wanted with JQuery - quick and dirty, though...
Tested with IE6 and FF 3. Download an example [here](http://cid-a1b54a42419a0b3e.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/%c3%96ffentlich/cursordisappearexample.7z)

Comment: Yes I speak german. 
But i don't want the cursor to be always invisible when you hover over that element.

And WOW. Stackoverflow is fast as hell. Thank you.

Comment: I think you have to use something like JQuery to add a CSS tag in the onClick event to make the cursor invisible and to remove this tag in an onMouseMove event.

Comment: Ok. We will try to fix it. Perhaps i'll have another idea. Anyhow, thanks for the fast help.