# C# Make the cursor disappear

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse-cursor, j#

I have a fullscreen c# application and I want that the cursor won't be visible while the user is in the application. (Controlling the application is solely with the keyboard)

Any one knows how to do such a thing?

PS : I prefer that the cursor will be completely unusable rather than "invisible" or "transparent"

Comment: is this when its on the form or totally hide it ?

Comment: This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446492/making-the-cursor-disappear

Comment: Do you mean the mouse pointer?

Comment: windows API, ShowCursor can be used to hide the cursor and ClipCursor can be used to limit its range

Comment: @SamMackrill, he's talking about a Winforms app, not a web app, that answer doesn't apply

Comment: @SamMackrill it has nothing to do with php

Comment: Ooops sorry I put the wrong link in apologies :) Anyway the answer is now given....

Comment: Cursor.Hide() Did the trick. by the way, I'm not sure if winAPI would help since I am not actually using c#, It's j# and thing are a little different here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# How can I hide the cursor in a winforms app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457360/c-sharp-how-can-i-hide-the-cursor-in-a-winforms-app)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the only option you'll have is to hide the cursor from what I can remember in the past

`Cursor.Hide()`

I had to do something similar to this in a touchscreen app in the past

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer the cursor to be completely unusable, then `Cursor.Hide()` won't fulfill your requirements, because the cursor is only hidden but still clickable. You'll need to add something like [this](http://www.monkeycancode.com/c-hide-mouse-disable-mouse-input) to disable clicking as well.

Answer (score -2):

vb.net: Me.Cursor = Cursors.No
c:.net: this.Cursor = Cursors.No

Comment: The "No" cursor is the crossed out circle symbol